# How does wp-polls plugin work (What is PHP's Anonymous Personalization methods and best practices)

Tags: php, session, cookies, wordpress

I know the title might be a bit broad but I chose it to encourage further coverage on this topic since there's not enough resources covering it.

What I've been told is that there's only 3 ways to recognize each user :

- Cookies : whether it's the usual cookie or a cookie containing
  session ID
- -URl : containing the usual `GET` data or session ID IP Adress
- User's IP Address

But I tried to workaround wp-polls(which is wordpress plugin for polls/surveys) just to see if I could vote more than one time (only for research purposes I swear :D)

this is the [URL](http://www.e3lam.org/2015/02/27/20393)(I'm sorry it's not English but I'm sure you'll find the plugin it's the on the left below the nav-bar)

so I tried

- Deleting the cookies that was sent by the website containing that
  plugin
- check the URL (didn't see  any session IDs)
- Browsing the website containing the plugin using a proxy server

The plugin detected me after deleting the cookies,( but when I browsed using the proxy server it detected me on that page but when I went to the Homepage and clicked the vote button it didn't do anything[rather than saying "you've already voted"] probably the proxy server conflicted with the Javascript of the ajax call)

My question is .. how does that plugin work and detect users (did it stopped working on purpose when I used the proxy server?) and what are the methods/best practices to detect users ?

Comment: Look through the code of the plugin to see how it works and detects users? It's as simple as that. You can also check local storage. Maybe it stores something there.

Comment: well , since there seems to be no answers I'll probably do that .. I just hoped for overall coverage of the topic

Answer (score 0):

On a poll that works with wp-polls I just deleted the cookie and it let's me vote again every time. I delete my local cookies indicating that I have voted. I believe that sends a working post request to the site every time and counts my vote. Wordpress dashboard does not show any IPs, only country of origin. There is info about visited pages in one of the views of cPanel (if that's what the site uses, most cases it is), but I doubt the host will check that. In that case, proxy is the necessary bypass.